# uniqueness of multiplicative zero of a ring

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. Fix $a\in R$. If $ab=0$ for all $b\in R$, must $a=0$? Here, $0$ denotes the unique element such that $0+b=b$ for all $b$.

Comment: Do rings have a one? If yes, then $a = a \cdot 1 = 0$.

Comment: Without a $1$, then you could have $ab=0$ for all $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you both.

Comment: You could write it up and post it as an answer, aaa.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that, aaa.

Answer (score 1):

[By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), a ring has a multiplicative identity $1$ that satisfies $a\cdot 1=a$ for all $a$. If $a\cdot b=0$ for all $b$, then in particular $a\cdot 1=0$, which implies $a=0$.

One the other hand, a "rng" is an object that satisfies all of the ring axioms except for the existence of $1$. It is easy to construct examples of rngs for which $a\ne 0$.

Take any abelian group $(R,+)$. Let $0$ denote the additive identity. Define a multiplication rule $a\cdot b=0$ for all $a,b\in R$. This satisfies associativity and distributivity. Therefore $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a rng.